# Session Empty when i redirect the page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, session-cookies

My session works fine when user logged in or logout, it works.But i have a problem when redirect the link.

Here is my config settings:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I just create the Javascript code in the view file that handles the click event only. 
Purpose of this click event is when user click on radio button it simply change the url simple javascript code like this:

```
document.location = "http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/sets/";
```

Problem: when this url changed my session user_data variable goes empty.i check by using the following code in sets controller:

```
class sets extends CI_Controller{
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('header');
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
   $this->load->view('footer');        
}
```

Result of this:

```
Array ( [session_id] => 421e7bec9096249af3f37142796005f2 [ip_address] => 00.115.429.81 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0 [last_activity] => 1395076388 [user_data] => )
```

er
Now i found that My user_data is empty

Comment: did you check if the session_id is changing? if so, your session isn't "sticking" and you end up with a brand new empty session.

Comment: probably you have more then one codeigniter application on that domain. If is so, rename the sess_cookie_name for one of them

Comment: i m not use db for session, what should i need to do?

Comment: hotzu , i replace the name from ci_session to ci_sessiona, but problem still same

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome with developer tools or Firefox with firebug?  If so, I ran into problems with that as well. It has to do with the user/agent string changing and not matching the current session (due to the developer tools). If you are using dev tools, you can try changing `$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;` to `$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;`

I would recommend changing that back in your production environment though.